# Hide part of a border in ul/li menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu that is comprised of `ul`/`li` elements. The `li`elements contain div's for formatting.

Here is the code:

http://jsbin.com/seqenoduze

(you'll need to resize the html,css, and javascript parts on the jsbin page to get the full-screen menu instead of the mobile menu)

When hovering over a menu item, there is a drop-down sub-menu which lists further items. It currently looks something like:

[image: Current Menu]

I am trying to cover over the part of the solid black border underneath the hovered/active Menu Item. Something like this:

[image: Desired Menu]

The idea is to give a "current tab" look and feel to the menu.

Code looks something like:

```
<nav id="catNavMenu">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="jetmenu-wrapper"><ul class="jetmenu blue"><li class="showhide" style="display: none;"><span class="title">MENU</span><span class="icon"><em></em><em></em><em></em><em></em></span></li>
            <li class="fix-sub" style=""> <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

                <div class="megamenu full-width" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#1">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#2">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fix-sub" style=""> <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

                <div class="megamenu full-width" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#1">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#2">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fix-sub" style=""> <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>

                <div class="megamenu full-width">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#1">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col2"><a href="#2">Sub Menu Item</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS like:

```
 nav#catNavMenu {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
/*
NAME: Jet Responsive Megamenu 
AUTHOR PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/user/marcoarib
ITEM PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/item/jet-responsive-megamenu/5719593
*/
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 @import"font-awesome.css";

/* MENU CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu {
    width: 98%;
    /*padding: 0;*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /*#333333;*/
    border-top: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
    border-left: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
    border right: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.jetmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.jetmenu a {
    -o-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
}
.jetmenu > li > a {
    padding: 10px 14px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}
.jetmenu > li:hover > a, .jetmenu > li.active > a {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
    border-right: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
    border-left: 2px dotted #d0d0d0;
}
/* DROPDOWN CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu ul.dropdown, .jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    min-width: 134px;
    background: #333333;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown {
    top: 60px;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown {
    left: 100%;
    top: inherit;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li a {
    width:100%;
    padding: 12px 24px 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
}
/* dropdowns to left side */
 .jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown.left {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
/* SUBMENU INDICATORS
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu .indicator {
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu ul li .indicator {
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 10px;
}
/* MEGAMENU
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu > li > .megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    /*#333333;*/
    width: 25%;
    /* top: 60px; */
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* megamenu list */
 .jetmenu li > .megamenu ul {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu ul li.title {
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
}
/* megamenu h5 */
 .jetmenu li > .megamenu h5 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* megamenu links */
 .jetmenu li > .megamenu a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s linear;
    transition: color 0.3s linear;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #dedede;
}
/* megamenu images */
 .jetmenu .megamenu img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    transition: border 0.3s linear;
}
/* to fix right attribute on submenus (menu aligned to left (default)) */
 .jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .megamenu, .jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .megamenu.half-width, .jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .dropdown {
    right: 0;
}
/* MEGAMENU WIDTHS
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu > li > .megamenu.half-width {
    width: 50%;
}
.jetmenu > li > .megamenu.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
/* MEGAMENU FORM CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu li > .megamenu form {
    width: 100%;
}
/* megamenu inputs */
 .jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"], .jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #999;
    background: #444;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    transition: border 0.3s linear;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #444;
    color: #777;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
}
/* MEGAMENU GRID SYSTEM
**********************************************************/
 .megamenu .row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.megamenu .row:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.megamenu .row:before, .megamenu .row:after {
    display: table;
    content:"";
    line-height: 0;
}
.megamenu .row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.megamenu .row .col1, .megamenu .row .col2, .megamenu .row .col3, .megamenu .row .col4, .megamenu .row .col5, .megamenu .row .col6 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    <!--margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;
    --> -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.megamenu .row[class*="col"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.megamenu .row .col1 {
    width: 14.893617021276595%;
}
.megamenu .row .col2 {
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
}
.megamenu .row .col3 {
    width: 48.93617021276595%;
}
.megamenu .row .col4 {
    width: 65.95744680851064%;
}
.megamenu .row .col5 {
    width: 82.97872340425532%;
}
.megamenu .row .col6 {
    width: 100%;
}
/*div.col2:hover {
    background-color: #9A0101;
}

a.q7 {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

a.q7:hover {
   background-color:#9A0101;
}

span.q7 {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

span:q7:hover {
   background-color: #9A0101;
}
*/
 a.q7 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
span.q7 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
/* RIGHT ALIGNMENT (MENU ITEM)
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu > li.right {
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.right > .megamenu, .jetmenu > li.right > .megamenu.half-width, .jetmenu > li.right > .dropdown {
    right: 0;
}
/* to fix right attribute on submenus (menu aligned to right) */
 .jetmenu > li.jsright {
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .megamenu, .jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .megamenu.half-width, .jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .dropdown {
    right: 0;
}
/* ICONS (FONT AWESOME)
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu > li > a > i {
    line-height: 23px !important;
    margin-right: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
}
/* COLLAPSIBLE MENU
**********************************************************/
 .jetmenu > li.showhide {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
    background: #333;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide span.title {
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide span.icon {
    margin: 17px 20px;
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide .icon em {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #999;
}
/* STYLES
**********************************************************/

/* black */
 .black > li:hover > a, .black > li.active > a {
    background: #111111;
    color: #fff;
}
.black ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #111111;
    color: #fff;
}
.black li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .black li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #111111;
}
.black li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #111111;
    color: #fff;
}
.black li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #dedede;
}
/* grey */
 .grey > li:hover > a, .grey > li.active > a {
    background: #82837E;
    color: #fff;
}
.grey ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #82837E;
    color: #fff;
}
.grey li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .grey li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #82837E;
}
.grey li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #82837E;
    color: #fff;
}
.grey li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #dedede;
}
/* blue */
 .blue > li:hover > a, .blue > li.active > a {
    background: #fff;
    /*#9A0101*/
    ;
    color: #999;
}
.blue ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #999;
}
.blue li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .blue li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #fff;
}
.blue li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #999;
}
.blue li > .megamenu a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#999;
    /*color: #FFF;*/
    /*#333333;*/
    /*#02b8fa;*/
}
/* deeper */
 .deeper > li:hover > a, .deeper > li.active > a {
    background: #008C9E;
    color: #fff;
}
.deeper ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #008C9E;
    color: #fff;
}
.deeper li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .deeper li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #008C9E;
}
.deeper li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #008C9E;
    color: #fff;
}
.deeper li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #008C9E;
}
/* green */
 .green > li:hover > a, .green > li.active > a {
    background: #88c425;
    color: #fff;
}
.green ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #88c425;
    color: #fff;
}
.green li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .green li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #88c425;
}
.green li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #88c425;
    color: #fff;
}
.green li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #88c425;
}
/* emerald */
 .emerald > li:hover > a, .emerald > li.active > a {
    background: #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
}
.emerald ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
}
.emerald li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .emerald li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}
.emerald li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
}
.emerald li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #2ecc71;
}
/* red */
 .red > li:hover > a, .red > li.active > a {
    background: #C21A01;
    color: #fff;
}
.red ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #C21A01;
    color: #fff;
}
.red li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .red li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #C21A01;
}
.red li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #C21A01;
    color: #fff;
}
.red li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #C21A01;
}
/* pox */
 .pox > li:hover > a, .pox > li.active > a {
    background: #FA023C;
    color: #fff;
}
.pox ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #FA023C;
    color: #fff;
}
.pox li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .pox li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #FA023C;
}
.pox li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #FA023C;
    color: #fff;
}
.pox li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #FA023C;
}
/* orange */
 .orange > li:hover > a, .orange > li.active > a {
    background: #ff670f;
    color: #fff;
}
.orange ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #ff670f;
    color: #fff;
}
.orange li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .orange li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #ff670f;
}
.orange li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #ff670f;
    color: #fff;
}
.orange li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #ff670f;
}
/* sunburst */
 .sunburst > li:hover > a, .sunburst > li.active > a {
    background: #D46D22;
    color: #fff;
}
.sunburst ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #D46D22;
    color: #fff;
}
.sunburst li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .sunburst li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #D46D22;
}
.sunburst li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #D46D22;
    color: #fff;
}
.sunburst li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #D46D22;
}
/* yellow */
 .yellow > li:hover > a, .yellow > li.active > a {
    background: #febf01;
    color: #222;
}
.yellow ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #febf01;
    color: #222;
}
.yellow li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .yellow li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #febf01;
}
.yellow li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #febf01;
    color: #222;
}
.yellow li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #febf01;
}
/* purple */
 .purple > li:hover > a, .purple > li.active > a {
    background: #a849a3;
    color: #fff;
}
.purple ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #a849a3;
    color: #fff;
}
.purple li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .purple li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #a849a3;
}
.purple li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #a849a3;
    color: #fff;
}
.purple li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #a849a3;
}
/* pink */
 .pink > li:hover > a, .pink > li.active > a {
    background: #F56991;
    color: #fff;
}
.pink ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    background: #F56991;
    color: #fff;
}
.pink li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .pink li > .megamenu form textarea:focus {
    border-color: #F56991;
}
.pink li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #F56991;
    color: #fff;
}
.pink li > .megamenu a:hover {
    color: #F56991;
}
/* RESPONSIVE LAYOUT
**********************************************************/
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .jetmenu {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .jetmenu > li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > a {
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
    .jetmenu a {
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        /*#333;*/
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown, .jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown {
        width: 100% !important;
        left: 0;
        position: static !important;
        border: none;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown li {
        background: #fff !important;
        border: none;
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown > li > a {
        padding-left: 40px !important;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu {
        width: 100% !important;
        position: static;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row[class*="col"] {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 15px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row:first-child[class*="col"]:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > a {
        padding-left: 40px !important;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > a {
        padding-left: 60px !important;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > a {
        padding-left: 80px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu {
        width: 100% !important;
        left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a `border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;` and other similar things to "cover up" the border there, but everything just seems to push the sub-menu downwards.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried a pseudo element to cover it? positioning them absolutely would mean they don't alter the other parts? Otherwise, a box shadow would/should also work, since it "doesn't take up space" in the actual dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element on the anchor to cover the border of the dropdown menu. For that I would create an active class and toggle it on mouseover/leave:

```
.fix-sub > a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.fix-sub.active > a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -1px;
}
```

JS part changed:

```
$(menu).find("li").bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.delay).fadeIn(settings.speed);
}).bind("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.hideDelay).fadeOut(settings.speed);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wejiluzilu/1/)

You could achieve the same effect (for the megamenu/dropdown) without the use of JavaScript and therefore I recommend you to refactor your code to only use CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:after` pseudo element like this:

```
.jetmenu > li:hover:after{
    content:"";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

You can change the white background to fit your menu element background, but in your case it's `white`

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nepofedusi/1/)

Answer (score 0):

here is a css only way:

```
.fix-sub a{position: relative;}
.fix-sub:hover::before {
  content:"";
  top:50px;
  position: absolute;
  background:#fff;
  height:2px;
  width:121px;
  display:inline;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.megamenu {
  z-index: 0!important;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/resutunuxa/2/